# Comparing Cached and Hashed dictionary

Tags: sql, dictionary, clickhouse

I'm trying to compare Cached and Hashed Clickhouse Dictionaries. What are some of the use cases for both, and where they overlap in strengths what are some queries I could launch to compare them?

Comment: official docs https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries/external-dictionaries/external-dicts-dict-layout/ ?

Comment: @vladimir Yep I've been through that several times although there's and if you had read it there's a section on achieving 99% hit rate for cache dictionaries to be effective and playing around with the parameters to fine tune the dictionary. What are the parameters I should be changing and how should I entry and achieve a 99% hit rate, and if I do get such a hit rate how should I then compare the results to hashed dictionaries.

Comment: hashed dictionary may require hundreds gigabytes of memory. Instead you can  use cached and adjust memory usage / hit-rate using  size_in_cells `<size_in_cells>1000000000</size_in_cells>`